# Building send and arrive times from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following data is about a person sending an IpHone 14 pro max to his wife. The Iphone 14 pro max
has to travel from America to China, China to Argentina and finally from Argentina to Saudi Arabia since the girl is at Saudi Arabia
watching FIFA.

```
CREATE TABLE IPhone (Id int, Country NVARCHAR(12), seqNo int, Send datetime2(0), Arrive datetime2(0));

INSERT INTO IPhone VALUES 
('1001','America','1', '2022-11-23 18:30:00.000',null),
('1002','China','2', '2022-11-24 08:18:00.000','2022-11-24 05:00:00'),
('1003','Argentina','3', '2022-11-25 18:30:00.000','2022-11-24 18:18:00.000'),
('1004','Saudi Arabia','4',null,'2022-11-25 20:30:00.000');
```

What I am trying to achieve is

1. Sent from America on 2022-11-23 18:30:00.000 and reached on China at
   2022-11-24 05:00:00
2. Sent from China on 2022-11-24 08:18:00.000 and
   reached on Argentina on 2022-11-24 18:18:00.000
3. Sent from Argentina
   on 2022-11-25 18:30:00.000 and reached on Saudi Arabia on 2022-11-25
   20:30:00.000

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am trying. I may need some ideas on how to achieve this. I'm quite confused to use Case or JOIN.

Comment: Your provided create table and insert data doesn't even run - maybe test that before posting

Comment: one question, seq always start with 1 ?

Comment: You defined your table `Send` and `Arrive` as `date` but the sample data show it is date & time. Also the date are not valid `2022-25-23`

Comment: @RajatJha Yes always start from 1

Comment: And there is not such date as `2022-25-23`

Comment: What  you need is just a `SELF JOIN`

Comment: @Squirrel I just updated. The SQL was wrong. Sorry about this

Comment: Still broken `NCHAR(10)` doesn't fit `Saudi Arabia` and why use `nchar` anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a self join to the next row as shown below. However I'm not convinced the desired results you show are correct, because you are using the arrive value of the next destination which seems odd.

```
CREATE TABLE IPhone (Id int, Country NVARCHAR(12), seqNo int, Send datetime2(0), Arrive datetime2(0));

INSERT INTO IPhone VALUES 
('1001','America','1', '2022-11-23 18:30:00.000',null),
('1002','China','2', '2022-11-24 08:18:00.000','2022-11-24 05:00:00'),
('1003','Argentina','3', '2022-11-25 18:30:00.000','2022-11-24 18:18:00.000'),
('1004','Saudi Arabia','4',null,'2022-11-25 20:30:00.000');

SELECT f.id, f.Country CountryFrom, t.Country CountryTo
    , convert(varchar(4),f.seqNo) + '-' + convert(varchar(4),t.seqNo) seqNo
    , f.Send, t.Arrive
FROM IPhone f
INNER JOIN IPhone t ON t.seqNo = f.seqNo + 1
ORDER BY id;
```

Which returns:

| id | CountryFrom | CountryTo | seqNo | Send | Arrive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | America | China | 1-2 | 2022-11-23 18:30:00 | 2022-11-24 05:00:00 |
| 1002 | China | Argentina | 2-3 | 2022-11-24 08:18:00 | 2022-11-24 18:18:00 |
| 1003 | Argentina | Saudi Arabia | 3-4 | 2022-11-25 18:30:00 | 2022-11-25 20:30:00 |

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nK5zz7Kx)

Note: Your sample data was broken:

- you were trying to store datetimes in a date
- you had incorrect dates
- you were storing numbers in strings
- and your string were too short for the data.

Getting this sort of thing right will make things much easier for the real work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function,

```
SELECT id
, Country AS CountryFrom
, LEAD(Country,1) OVER (ORDER BY SeqNo) AS CountryTo
, CAST(seqNo AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(LEAD(seqNo,1) OVER (ORDER BY SeqNo) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS seqNo
, Send
, LEAD (Arrive,1) OVER (ORDER BY SeqNo) AS Arrive
FROM Iphone
```

Comment: Actually this is wonderful approach. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions if you don't have to much data is.

[FiddleDemo](https://dbfiddle.uk/HFsp1ML9)

```
select
Id, Country countryFrom, 
    (select top 1 Country from IPhone c where c.seqNo > IPhone.seqNo ) CountryTo, 
    Send_date,
    (select top 1 Arrive_date from IPhone c where c.seqNo > IPhone.seqNo ) Arrive

from IPhone
```

[image]

Other way would be to link over seq_no

```
select 
    IPhone.Id,
    IPhone.Country,
    c.country,
    IPhone.Send_date,
    c.Arrive_date
from IPhone
left join IPhone c on IPhone.seqNo + 1 = c.seqNo
```

Edit: As Dale mentioned you, your create table script is not ok so I've stored values as nvarchar values.